# Overriding constructors in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, overriding

For school I need to learn Java and since I'm used to C++ (like Cocoa/Objective-C) based languages, I get really frustrated on Java.

I've made a super-class (that can also be used as a base-class):

```
public class CellView {
    public CellViewHelper helper; // CellViewHelper is just an example

    public CellView() {
        this.helper = new CellViewHelper();
        this.helper.someVariable = <anything>;

        System.out.println("CellView_constructor");
    }
    
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("CellView_draw");
    }

    public void needsRedraw() {
        this.draw();
    }

}

public class ImageCellView extends CellView {

    public Image someImage;

    public ImageCellView() {
        super();
        this.someImage = new Image();
        System.out.println("ImageCellView_constructor");
    }

    public void setSomeParam() {
        this.needsRedraw(); // cannot be replaced by this.draw(); since it's some more complicated.
    }

    @Override public void draw() {
        super.draw();
        System.out.println("ImageCellView_draw");
    }

}
```

Now, when I call it like this:

```
ImageCellView imageCellView = new ImageCellView();
imageCellView.setSomeParam();
```

I get this:

> CellView_constructor
>
> ImageCellView_constructor
>
> CellView_draw

However, I want it to be:

> CellView_constructor
>
> ImageCellView_constructor
>
> CellView_draw
>
> ImageCellView_draw

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,

Tim

**EDIT:**

I also implemented this method to CellView:

```
public void needsRedraw() {
    this.draw();
}
```

And this to ImageCellView:

```
public void setSomeParam() {
    this.needsRedraw(); // cannot be replaced by this.draw(); since it's some more complicated.
}
```

And I've been calling this:

```
ImageCellView imageCellView = new ImageCellView();
imageCellView.setSomeParam();
```

Does this causes the problem (when I call a function from the super it calls to the super *only*)? How can I solve this... (without having to redefine/override the needsRedraw()-method in every subclass?)

Comment: is your first output correct ? it doesn't seem like

Comment: Something is amiss here in what is being reported.

Comment: Also this stuff is one area where Java is not different from C++.

Comment: Your code already works. You should clarify your problem.

Comment: @Colin, I updated my code to show you some more calls the code made... It's quite complicated (the whole code even more :P)

Comment: @Tim van Elsloo: Please update your original code so that a) it's short and complete (no external dependencies) and b) make sure the output you describe actually matches reality. (It doesn't at the moment.)

Comment: @Tim van Elsloo, Even so, it's still working.

Comment: Objective-C isn't really "C++ based".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get proper output.

I tried you example just commented unrelated things:

```
import java.awt.Image;

public class CellView {
    //public CellViewHelper helper; // CellViewHelper is just an example

    public CellView() {
        //this.helper = new CellViewHelper();
        //this.helper.someVariable = <anything>;

        System.out.println("CellView_constructor");
    }

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("CellView_draw");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageCellView imageCellView = new ImageCellView();
        imageCellView.draw();
    }
}

class ImageCellView extends CellView {

    public Image someImage;

    public ImageCellView() {
        super();
        //this.someImage = new Image();
        System.out.println("ImageCellView_constructor");
    }

    @Override public void draw() {
        super.draw();
        System.out.println("ImageCellView_draw");
    }

}
```

and I get following output:

> CellView_constructor
>
> ImageCellView_constructor
>
> CellView_draw
>
> ImageCellView_draw

**This is exactly what you want, and this is what your code print's.**

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I placed the output in the wrong order... I actually mean that ImageCellView_draw isn't called and I don't understand why...

Comment: It still doesn't get called (there's no "ImageCellView_draw" in the output).
I updated my code to show you some more methods.

Comment: That's weird, this works, but the same code (with other class-names and some imports to awt.Graphics) doesn't work... Looks like there's something wrong with my Graphics-implementation. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Why I didn't get any points for this question though this was rated up and selected ?

Comment: @Yok You randomly decided to delete massive parts of your question and restore them, which pushed you over the <3 = Community Wiki limit

Comment: Thanks @Lord.Quackstar. Question was posted I answered it accordingly. Then asker changed question considerably which made my earlier answer invalid, So I had to delete my earlier answer and post new one. Next time onwards I will mark answer for delete and post new answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "you can't."

Objects are constructed from the bottom up, calling base class initializers before subclass initializers and base class consrtuctors before subclass constructors.

EDIT:

The code you have looks good, based on your edit.  I would go through the mundane tasks like ensuring that you have compiled your code after you've added you `System.out.println` calls to your subclass

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I placed the output in the wrong order... I actually mean that ImageCellView_draw isn't called and I don't understand why...

Comment: I updated my code to show you some more methods (including a super-call which may cause the problem?).